# Adding values from a text file using a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, addition

So I'm working with two classes and a text file. In my main I have all my getters and setters, but I'm trying to find the sum of the pay, and I can't figure it out. Here's what I have so far:

```
private static void printStats(Worker[] people, int count) {

    double total = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) 
        total += people[i];
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Also, I'm just starting out so I don't have a good grasping of the concept and I'm genuinely lost. :-/

Here's my Worker class:

public class Worker {

```
private String first;
private String last;
private int total_hrs;
private double pay;

public Worker(String last, String first, int total_hrs, double pay) {

    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.total_hrs = total_hrs;
    this.pay = pay;

}

public void setFirst(String first) {

    this.first = first;

}

public void setLast(String last) {

    this.last = last;

}

public void setTotal_hrs(int total_hrs) {

    this.total_hrs = total_hrs;

}

public void setPay(double pay) {

    this.pay = pay;

}

public String getFirst() {

    return first;

}

public String getLast() {

    return last;

}

public int getTotal_hrs() {

    return total_hrs;

}

public double getPay() {

    return pay;

}
```

Comment: please post the worker class

Comment: You can sum only numeric types like int/double/float etc, not arbitrary user-defined types like Worker. You need to invoke a getter of the Worker instance to retrieve the number to sum i.e. `total += people[i].get<SomeThing>()`

Comment: `total += people[i].getPay()`

Comment: If your code shows an error, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printStats(Worker[] people, int count) {

    double total = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) 
        total += people[i].getTotal_hrs();
}
```

calling `people[i]` is just accessing a `Worker` object. Once you have the object, you need to call `getTotal_hrs()` to get the hours of the worker at index i in he array. Or getPay() or whatever you're trying to sum, but it must be double, int, etc.